# Networking in Docker Compose file

Tags: docker, networking, service, docker-compose, hyperlink

I am writing a docker compose file for my web app.If I use 'link' to connect services with each other do I also need to include 'port'? And is 'depends on' an alternate option of 'links'? What will be best for connection services in a compose file with one another?

Comment: 'links' is a legacy feature of docker compose that's going to go away. Suggest to use "user-defined networks". More [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core setup for this is described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  If you do absolutely nothing, then one service can call another using its name in the `docker-compose.yml` file as a host name, using the port the process inside the container is listening on.

Up to startup-order issues, here's a minimal `docker-compose.yml` that demonstrates this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: nginx
  client:
    image: busybox
    command: wget -O- http://server/
    # Hack to make the example actually work:
    # command: sh -c 'sleep 1; wget -O- http://server/'
```

You shouldn't use `links:` at all.  It was an important part of first-generation Docker networking, but it's not useful on modern Docker.  (Similarly, there's no reason to put `expose:` in a Docker Compose file.)

You always connect to the port the process inside the container is running on.  `ports:` are optional; if you have `ports:`, cross-container calls always connect to the *second* port number and the remapping doesn't have any effect.  In the example above, the `client` container always connects to the default HTTP port 80, even if you add `ports: ['12345:80']` to the `server` container to make it externally accessible on a different port.

`depends_on:` affects two things.  Try adding `depends_on: [server]` to the `client` container to the example.  If you look at the "Starting..." messages that Compose prints out when it starts, this will force `server` to start starting before `client` starts starting, but this is *not* a guarantee that `server` is up and running and ready to serve requests (this is a very common problem with database containers).  If you start only part of the stack with `docker-compose up client`, this also causes `server` to start with it.

A more complete typical example might look like:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    # The Dockerfile COPYs static content into the image
    build: ./server-based-on-nginx
    ports:
      - '12345:80'
  client:
    # The Dockerfile installs
    # https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it
    build: ./client-based-on-busybox
    # ENTRYPOINT and CMD will usually be in the Dockerfile
    entrypoint: wait-for-it.sh server:80 --
    command: wget -O- http://server/
    depends_on:
      - server
```

SO questions in this space seem to have a number of other unnecessary options.  `container_name:` explicitly sets the name of the container for non-Compose `docker` commands, rather than letting Compose choose it, and it provides an alternate name for networking purposes, but you don't really need it.  `hostname:` affects the container's internal host name (what you might see in a shell prompt for example) but it has no effect on other containers.  You can manually create `networks:`, but Compose provides a `default` network for you and there's no reason to not use it.